# Can I put road salt into toilet/sink trap to prevent it from freezing?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, freezing, winter

I have been advised, that I can put salt into a trap to prevent the water from freezing in building I do not use much during tough part of the winter. I know I need to remove all water from pipes where possible, but I would like to avoid manually sucking the water from traps, especially from toilets.

My questions:

- can I use road salt, or is it safer to use the salt used for human consumtion? In other words - is something wrong in road salt that could damage the pipes?
- what is correct dosage of road salt (for sink, toilet) if I do expect about -20 degress celsius as the lowest outdoor temperature possible (small building).

Comment: thete is nothing wrong with salt ... it just happens to promote corrosion ... why don't you use RV antifreeze?

Comment: Because I have 50kg of road salt I do not need.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong here, but I'd think the _drain_ lines are the least of your worries. If your drains function properly, you'll have a little bit of water in each trap and otherwise completely empty pipes. There _should_ be enough room for the water to expand in the pipes as it freezes _without_ breaking the trap. The supply lines, however, are full of water from one end to the other all the time and if they freeze, there is nowhere for the expansion except out of the pipe through a break. Also, draining the traps can allow sewer gas into the building which you _don't_ want.

Comment: @FreeMan traps freeze, and it's a really easy way to make a right mess of a toilet (ceramic is not a big fan of expanding and contracting.) Traps commonly freeze at the surface first, so that plugs the rest of the trap and further freezing results in pressure rising in the trapway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your plan is OK except that -20C is about the lowest you are going to get protection with NaCl (i.e. common salt).  Here is a graph of freeze point vs. concentration.  You really cannot get a higher concentration than about 23% since excess salt precipitates out.

I think you'll be better off using an anti-freeze product.

[image: Freeze point vs. concentration]

Comment: Good point, but building interiors rarely approach actual outdoor temps due to solar gain.  If the coldest outdoor temp will be -20C, salt should do fine.

Comment: @isherwood  I'm just going by what the OP said: "...if I do expect about -20 degress celsius..."

Comment: So am I. You cut the sentence off partway. :)

Comment: The inside temp could reach the outside temp.

Comment: I'd probably try a bit of anti-freeze intended for automotive windscreens. That stuff tends to hold till -25 and is cheap and easy to get by. But if you go that route, a bit of pure (cleaning) alcohol might not be a bad idea either.

Comment: @Mast Most people use "RV" antifreeze for this purpose.  It's environmentally safe and good to -45C or -50F.  It's also relatively inexpensive.

Comment: @Mast wouldn't the alcohol evaporate rather quickly, though?

Comment: @user35915 Probably, that's a good reason to stick with glycol-solutions like anti-freeze :-)

Comment: @Mast *Do not* use automotive antifreeze. It's pretty toxic, and pouring it down the drain is illegal in most places. There are antifreeze solutions specifically made for toilets, so use those.

Comment: Salt is pretty good way below -20C. These solutions do freeze, but they lack the rigidity of the pure ice and don't break tubes.

Comment: I'd avoid salt if the traps or any downstream pipes are metal.   Bathroom sinks often have a movable stopper, I'd plan to replace that in the spring if it's not 100% plastic.